# Recursive search and grouping based on particular column in Postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql, output, jsonb, recursive-query

I am doing a recursive search in  one single table in Postgresql using Recursive CTE and output the result to in particular JSON format

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
SELECT subject ,predicate ,obj ,start_date,0 AS level FROM table1
where obj_status <> 'DELETE' or rel_status<> 'DELETE' or sub_status <> 'DELETE'
UNION ALL
select c.subject ,c.predicate ,c.obj ,c.start_date,e.level + 1 
FROM table1 c
 JOIN cte e ON c.subject = e.predicate
 )SELECT json_agg(row_to_json(integ))  FROM 
    (SELECT subject,json_agg(json_build_object(
                                  'predicate',predicate,
                                  'object' ,obj,
                                  'start_date' ,start_date)) as relation
            from cte
             group by subject,predicate ,obj ,start_date) as integ ;
```

When I run this I getting out put as

[image]

I am expecting my output as

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, Arun! Could you format the output that's shown in the two pictures as code instead of images, like you did with your search function? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors